# why angular directive could only have one root element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this error when I use angular's directive.

```
  Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'header' must have exactly one root element. /apps/dhe.techForm/views/directives/header.html
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$compile/tplrt?p0=header&p1=%2Fapps%2Fdhe.techForm%2Fviews%2Fdirectives%2Fheader.html
        at angular.js:68
        at angular.js:8512
        at processQueue (angular.js:14792)
        at angular.js:14808
        at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
        at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870)
        at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
        at done (angular.js:10589)
        at completeRequest (angular.js:10787)
        at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10728)
```

So if my directive's html like following, will throw angular error

```
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

directive's html like following is okay.

```
<section>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</section>
```

Why angular directive could only have one root element?

Comment: That is absolutely fine. That has to be that way. What is the issue using/wrapping it in one element?

Comment: Maybe reading the official docs would help: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt

Answer (score 0):

When your directive is configured to replace the directive element rather than its contents angular needs a single root element to use as the replacement.

Replacing the directive element works like a swap operation in that it just swaps the directive element with the root element of the directive template.  If there's not a single root element, this swap is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may used `replace: true` in your directive and that's why when angular want to replace element need one root element.

When a directive is declared with `template` (or `templateUrl`) and replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the `templateUrl` must be contained within a single html element.

to avoid this you can try without `replace: true` property in your directive.

you may use like:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function factory() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'someUrl'
  }
});
```

try now:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function factory() {
    return {
       templateUrl: 'someUrl'
    }
});
```